# null references for Random integers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a ViewModel, which has two values (Val1 & Val2), which I use for a simple reality test in my contact form.

```
public class ContactFormViewModel
{
    private Random Random { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public int Val1 => Random.Next(1, 9);
    public int Val2 => Random.Next(6, 19);
}
```

I try to use this in the view like this.

```
@model TraderToolkit.WebUI2.Models.EmailViewModels.ContactFormViewModel
//parts removed for brevity
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div class="container">
   <div class="form-group">
      <form role="form" action="" method="post" id="registrationForm">
       //parts removed for brevity
           <label for="RealTest">What is <span id="val1">@Model.Val1</span> +    <span id="val2">@Model.Val2</span>? </label>
           <div class="input-group">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="RealTest" id="RealTest" required>
               <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></i></span>
           </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary hidden" id="Send" name="Send" value="Send"></button>
        </div>
     </form>
   </div>
</div>
}
```

The error when running the sire and clicking to the contact form is a null reference exception, not set to an instance of the object. This makes sense as the class is never "newed" up. Since I am new to MVC, is this possible within a view? If not how do I instantiate this class so I can access Val1 and Val2 in the view?

Solution thanks to HaukurHaf

updated model

```
 public class ContactFormViewModel
{

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public int Val1 { get; set; }
    public int Val2 { get; set; }

    public ContactFormViewModel()
    {
        var rnd = new Random();
        Val1 = rnd.Next(1, 9);
        Val2 = rnd.Next(6, 19);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try defining a default constructor and initialize the random integers there:

```
public class ContactFormViewModel
{
    private Random Random { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public int Val1 { get; set; }
    public int Val2 { get; set; }

    public ContactFormViewModel()
    {
        Val1 = Random.Next(1,9);
        Val2 = Random.Next(6,19);
    }
}
```

Comment: Although a valid suggestion, one that I will incorporate, it does not solve the problem as the class still isn't newed up, therefore it doesn't run the constructor.

Comment: You should create an instance of the model in your controller and pass it to the view ...

Comment: The view is for a class ContactIs from my domain model, how do Ichange it to use the ViewModel?

Comment: The first line in your view (the one that starts with @model ....) is the one that "tells" the view which model to use. Is TraderToolkit.WebUI2.Models.EmailViewModels.ContactFormViewModel a domain model?  The naming convention suggests that it's a simple ViewModel.

Comment: It is a simple view model, I will change that. I want to save each contact request in the db. I'll convert the ViewModel to the domain class upon sending

Comment: Actually, I had already changed to using the ViewModel once I added the constructor. Still getting same error. Doesn't the model have to be instantiated in order to use it? Add var cfvm= new ContactFormViewModel(); in controller method and pass that to view?

Comment: Yes, it does.  Inside the controller, in the ActionResult, you need to do something like this:  ContactFormViewModel model = new ContactFormViewModel(); and then return View(model);